# In Visual Studio2010 "warning C4028: formal parameter 1 different from declaration" is displayed

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

Hi I have the below  code

I am getting the warning as 
"warning C4028: formal parameter 1 different from declaration"

I am not sure where i went wrong. I think my declararion of parameter is correct but pls help me.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <conio.h>
# include <math.h>

main()
{
    int x,y(),z,sqrt(int),cube(int);
    printf("Enter any number:");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    z=(x>y() ? sqrt(x):cube(x));
    printf("%d",z);
    getche();
    return 0;
}
int sqrt(int a)
{
    printf("Square:");
    return(a*a);
}
int cube(int b)
{
    printf("Cube:");
    return(b*b*b);
}
int y()
{
    return(10);
}
```

Comment: If you check the standard C math library, you will see that there is a function already called `sqrt` in it.

Answer (score 5):

```
int x,y(),z,sqrt(int),cube(int);
```

`sqrt` is already a C library function declared in `math.h` with a different prototype.

You have to rename your `sqrt` function  to something else.

Comment: Alternatively, don't #include <math.h>.  You don't need it.